# Ubuntu 20.04: black screen when reboot after unplug from thinkpad thunderbolt dock station

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, dock, thunderbolt

I have a thinkpad x395 (AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 3500U) with Ubuntu 20.04. It used to work quite well.

Recently I purchased a [thinkpad thunderbolt 3 workstation dock gen 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M6S81CM). My x395 works well when connecting to the dock (the dock is connecting with two 1080p external monitors). When the laptop is turned on, i have no issues if connecting or disconnecting to the dock.

The only issue is when the laptop is turned off and then disconnected from the dock, I can never manage to get into the Ubuntu system. When I turned on the laptop (with internal battery only), Ubuntu kernel started to boot, then the built-in display soon became black (GDM does not show up) and the system froze. I cannot get into the console either. Sometimes I can see a frozen mouse cursor. However, it can boot fine when connecting to the dock.

I tried the same hardware with fedora 32 and there was no problem at all. So there should be nothing wrong with the hardware. Both the laptop and the dock has been updated to the newest firmware.

OS:  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64

Host: 20NL000TCD ThinkPad X395

Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic

DE: GNOME

WM: Mutter

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 3500U w/ Radeon

GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Picasso

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with amd gpu. It has nothing to do with the dock.

Either upgrade the kernel >=5.6 or add a kernel parameter "iommu=soft" would solve it.

Comment: I tried `iommu=soft` in my `/etc/default/grub` file but that did not help. Still need to disconnect the docking station before reboot.